# Open Graph Aggregation filters - filter by time?

Tags: aggregation, facebook-opengraph

We'd like to filter by actions which haven't yet reached their end_time.

We can select 'end_time' as the filter field, but how do we specify the current time? We've tried time() and now() but these both produce a 'Something went wrong...' error message when saving. The aggregation saves fine without the filter so I presume the syntax must be incorrect on the filter?

Comment: have you found the solution for that?